# How to reduce a garden rocker's squeaking?

Tags: squeak

Last night I finished mounting a garden rocker (it's something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7jOY.jpg)).
It looks and feels nice but unfortunately it's very, very squeaky when used, especially when I'm barely moving it.

Is there anything I can do to attenuate the squeaking? 
I was thinking about changing the springs or adding some sort of rubber to the current springs.

The current rocker's spring looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the fasteners in the frame are thoroughly tight, put a drop of 3-in-1 oil on the end of each spring where it goes through the eye and contacts metal (two on the upper end for each side) and see if that gets rid of most of it.

Squeaking is caused by metal-on-metal contact where there's minute movement and no lubricant. Changing out the springs won't take care of where the squeaks usually come from.

After lubricating the spring ends, if it's still squeaking, have someone sit in the swing and observe the bolted joints for slight movement. If they're reasonably tight, you might hit them with something like Tri-flow lubricant spray between the joined pieces and wipe the residue off. The spring coils wouldn't be hurt by a little of that either as an anti-corrosive.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations! I'll try what you suggested and see if it will fix it

Comment: Glad to be of help! Squeaks like that can be like fingernails on a chalkboard and remove all the joy out of why you bought the swing.